# MAK or KMS for Windows 7 iso download

Tags: windows, windows-7, installation

I have a MAK and a KMS for Windows 7 Professional SP1 64-bit.

My Windows 7 dvd is malfunctioning and now I want to know if it is possible to download a ISO from Microsoft.

Is the MAK or KMS a valid product key for downloading directly from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7 ?

I dont have access to the keys right now so I can not try it. I just need to be prepared if it does not work when I get hold of my keys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, OEM, KMS or MAK Keys are not allowed to download the ISO. Get the ISO from MSDN or the VLSC portal.